# Two questions after a random choice on python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a text based game on python 3.3.2 and want to have to have two questions after a random choice this is my code:

```
if attack_spider == "Y":
    attack = ['Miss', 'Miss', 'Miss', 'Miss', 'Hit']
    from random import choice
    print(choice(attack))
    messages = {
        "Miss": "You made the spider angry! The spider bites you do you attack it again? Y/N",
        "Hit": "You killed the spider! It's fangs glow red do you pick them up? Y/N!"
    }

    print(messages[choice(attack)])
```

I want to be able to have different questions depending on weather you hit or miss if I just put:

```
spider = input()
if spider == "Y":
    print("as you pick the fangs up the begin to drip red blood")
```

it would should this even if you missed which has nothing to do with making the spider angry.
it there a way of getting different answer depending on if you hit or miss.

I added the code from the answer below.

```
               if attack_spider == "Y":
                   attack = choice(attack)
                   attack = ['Miss', 'Miss', 'Miss', 'Miss', 'Hit']
                   from random import choice
                   print (choice(attack))
                   messages = {
                       "Miss": "You made the spider angry! The spider bites you do you attack it again? Y/N",
                       "Hit": "You killed the spider! It's fangs glow red do you pick them up? Y/N!"
                   }

                   print(messages[choice(attack)])
                   spider = input()
                   if spider == "Y":
                       if attack == "Hit":
                           print("As you pick the fangs up the begin to drip red blood")

                       if attack == "Miss":
                           print("As you go to hit it it runs away very quickly")

                   if spider == "N":
                       if attack == "Hit":
                           print("As you walk forward and turn right something flies past you")

                       if attack == "Miss":
                           print("The spider begins to bite harder and you beging to See stars")
```

I know get this error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\callum\Documents\programming\maze runner.py", line 29, in <module>
        attack = choice(attack)
    NameError: name 'choice' is not defined
```

Comment: As a side note, it's recommended to do the imports at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Although in a way it's nicer when the imports are where they are used; some languages (e.g. Scala) even encourages this: it has the advantage of keeping it clear what the import is for, and also that when the code gets removed or commented out, the so does the import.

Comment: I have tried to solve this myself

Comment: @ErikAllik, thank you for the informative note about Scala, but [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) says that "*imports are always put at the top of the file*, just after any module comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants".

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: thank you for the sarcasm, but I'm very well aware of what PEP8 thinks about it; that doesn't invalidate my the content of my remark though (especially because it started with "in a way ..."), unless you're a fanatic worshipper of PEP8.

Comment: @ErikAllik, no sarcasm intended, sorry about that. What I was trying to say was that even if Scala (with which I'm not very familiar) guides recommend something, PEP8 should prevail because the code is written in Python.

Comment: @CristianCiupitu: I merely said "although, in a way, it's nicer ..."—I didn't necessarily say the PEP8 should be ignored in real-life code, but that it might actually be nicer to have localized imports, even though PEP8 thinks otherwise; there's no need to be fixated to PEP8, at least not when discussing various possibilities, otherwise we can just throw away our brains and happily live by the PEP8 forever.

Comment: @ErikAllik, right, even PEP8 says: "But most importantly: know when to be inconsistent -- sometimes the style guide just doesn't apply. When in doubt, use your best judgment.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `print(choice(attack))` needs to first assign to a variable:

```
hit_or_miss = random.choice(attack)
print(hit_or_miss)
```

And then you can do

```
if spider == "Y":
    if hit_or_miss == "Hit":
        print(...)

    if hit_or_miss == "Miss":
        print(...)

if spider == "N":
    if hit_or_miss == "Hit":
        print(...)

    if hit_or_miss == "Miss":
        print(...)
```

Since you already know dictionaries, this can also be done:

```
responses = {
    ("Y", "Hit"):  ...,
    ("Y", "Miss"): ...,
    ("N", "Hit"):  ...,
    ("N", "Miss"): ...
}

print(responses[spider, hit_or_miss])
```

Comment: I added the code but it does not show the text just closes the program

Comment: You didn't add the code from my post properly. Look particularly at the *first* code block from my post.

Comment: Ah, yeah, it's meant to be `random.choice`, not just `choice`. I'll update.

Comment: Note that your code won't work because of the order of operations. You define `attack` to be an element from `attack` before defining `attack`! Then you import `random` (which you need to have in order to use `random.choice`), then choose a *different* item to print!